# why syntax error near unexpected token ' fi '

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

#

#

#

#

echo -e "please insert user name :"

read un

echo "$un"

len=${#un}

echo "$len"

ze=0

te=10

if [ "$len" -eq "$ze" ]

than

echo "no argument"

exit

fi

if [ "$len" -ge "$te" ]

than

echo "the Argument maximum 10 alphanumeric"

exit

fi
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short: spelling error: it's `then`, not `than`.

Longer story: the syntax of the `if` command is this (boldface characters mark words that cannot be omitted or replaced):

> **if** test-commands; **then**
>     commands;
>   **fi**

where you can replace the `;` token with a new line character.

The shell will interpret `than` as part of *test-commands*, but then it finds a `fi` statement, which is incorrect (and, yes, *unexpected*) because it never encountered the `then` part.